# How to use an HTML entity in a Rails "content_tag" attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view-helpers

I've got a Rails 3 helper which needs to generate elements which might have HTML entities in the attribute values.  For example:

```
content_tag(:input, nil, :type => 'button', :value => 'Redo &#x21bb;')
```

I end up with this: `<input type="button" value="Redo &#x21bb;" />`
but what I want is: `<input type="button" value="Redo ↻" />`.

How can I tell Rails not to escape HTML entities in my content tag attributes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default rails escapes the content before printing it. You have to explicitly declare the content is safe to ouput:

You can do it using the raw helper, or the string method html_safe:

```
content_tag(:input, nil, :type => 'button', :value => 'Redo &#x21bb;'.html_safe)
```

or

```
content_tag(:input, nil, :type => 'button', :value => raw('Redo &#x21bb;'))
```